On equivalence of unitary matrices and unitary operators
I'm self-studying Axler's LADR and am working on the section on Unitary Operators. He defines a unitary operator as an invertible isometry. We've proved the following equivalences: 
He then defines a Unitary Matrix as an $n$x$n$ matrix whose columns are orthonormal in $F^n$. I understand how an operator is unitary if and only if its matrix is unitary with respect to some orthonormal basis. I'm trying to understand the following equivalences, which are left as an exercise for the reader. This feels like an important moment, and I'm trying to figure out if I've missed something.

Here's what I've done so far:
Throughout, let $T$ be the operator whose matrix is $Q$ with respect to the standard basis of $F^n$.
$a\implies b$: $Q$ is a unitary matrix, therefore $T$ is a unitary operator. Therefore the rows of the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis (ie the rows of $Q$) are orthonormal in $F^n$ with respect to the standard inner product, by 7.53e.
$b\implies c$: The rows of $Q$ are orthonormal, so $T$ is unitary by the equivalence $7.53e \implies a$. Thus $||{Tv}|| = ||v||$. Since $Q$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to an orthonormal basis, $||Q M(v)|| = ||Tv||$. Where $M(v)$ is just the column vector of $v$ with respect to the standard basis.
$c\implies d$: ||Qv|| = ||v|| so ||Tv|| = ||v|| as above, so $T$ is unitary. Thus, $ M(I) = M(T T^\star) = M(T)M(T^\star) = Q Q^\star = Q^\star Q$, where the last equals is true because $T T^\star = T^\star T = I$.
$d\implies a$: $M(I) = Q^\star Q = M(T^\star) M(T) = M(T^\star T)$ and $M(I) = Q Q^\star = M(T)M(T^\star)  = M(T T^\star)$. So $T T^\star = T^\star T = I$, and $T$ is a unitary operator by 7.53, so $Q$ is a unitary matrix.
This all feels somewhat clumsy to me switching back and forth between $Q$ and $T$-- am I taking the correct approach here? Is this the idea the author likely has in mind, or is the idea to do these proofs more directly with matrices, avoiding transitioning between $T$ and $Q$?
I would appreciate anyone's thoughts in better understanding this equivalence and the relationship between unitary operators and matrices. Thanks!

This looks fine to me. You could do the proofs directly with matrices but you'd just be repeating the proofs of the equivalences in 7.53. Once you understand the translation between unitary operators and unitary matrices it should become routine how to turn statements about one into equivalent statements about the other, this is practice doing that.

@QiaochuYuan thank you very much for looking
